# IIS server is not reflecting the changes?

Tags: iis, deployment, server, angular6

I have built an application using Angular 6 and built dist folder and uploaded it to  IIS server then it is reflecting changes but now  if I make any new changes an upload it then IIS server is not reflecting changes, I don't know why it is happening. 
I am  using firebase Real Time, In my project I just added image uploading functionality,
Before this issue I was getting Server error 404 `404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` so to get rid off such issue I added `{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }` this in my project but I uploaded it but changes not seen.
Please help what might be cause of this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to refresh site in iis or restart iis server.[image](https://i.imgur.com/jdIwwoB.png)also clear browser cache and browse the page.

Comment: I post this solution please mark as answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to refresh the site in iis or restart iis server.also clear browser cache and browse the page.

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: I did what you said But it didn't refresh my python (Django) codes.

Comment: Your answer doesnt make sense. Refresh is a non-disruptive action in the IIS Manager used to update the view.
Restart is a disruptive action that stops and starts websites or application pools, impacting users of those services.